# Can we use F() macro of arduino with altsoftserial

Tags: arduino-uno

I am using Arduino uno and i am running out of SRAM. 
I came through F() Macro but it saved memory for Serial.println() and with software serial object.

But most of my code use Altsoftserial libraray object and there i do not see any SRAM memory change if i use F() macro in print.

Please let me know if F() macro can be used with altSoftserial or not ??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps this should be moved to http://arduino.stackexchange.com/ ?